# Batch build using IAR tools

Tags: build, embedded, iar

I am trying to do a batch build of a project using IAR tools. The processor is a CC2530, and it builds fine in the IDE. I have followed the documentation for batch build (Project/Batch Build) and created a .cspy file that is suppose to be my batch file, but in the comments in that file it indicates that I need a debug file (.ubrof) to execute with it. I can't find a .ubrof file and I have searched the whole project directory structure. Also, I want my batch build to build a production version without the debugging information.

Where do I get a .ubrof file?
How do I do a production batch build using IAR tools?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My understanding of your question is that you want to build the firmware image using a command line from within a batch file.  I use the IAR tools for MSP430 and AVR32 processor families and the command line used to invoke the IAR build process from the command line is

`iarbuild "Project_File.ewp" -make BUILD_NAME -log info`

where BUILD_NAME is the build configuration ("Debug" or "Release" are the two default options).  The syntax of the iarbuild command is in the Embedded workbench manual.

The UBROF file is the binary output file that the tools produce and that you fould normally load into your target for debugging.  I would normally have the tools produce a UBROF file for debugging and a hex or s-record image file to be used for device programming in production.

Answer (score 1):

.cspy is related to the C-Spy debugger; you do not need it to *build* the project.

.ubrof is an object file format used by IAR, it is the result of a successful build (if the project is configured to produce such a file).

The IAR command line build utility (iarbuild.exe), and the C-Spy command line utility (cspybat.exe) are discussed [here](http://www.iar.com/website1/1.0.1.0/1882/1/)

Comment: Archived version of the link above (which now goes to a 404): https://web.archive.org/web/20100628010141/http://www.iar.com/website1/1.0.1.0/1882/1/

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to call the iar compilers/assemblers/linkers from the command line. This might be beneficial, if you already have some build framework (make, cmake, scons, etc) -- you can then use other toolchains for the same sources. For a example a native toolchain to generate unit tests from your code.

The big disadvantage of this approach is that it requires an additional (duplicate) description of what is already in the iar project files: Which files to use, which compile flags to apply. This clearly violates DRY.

Answer (score 0):

IAR's IDE supports "Batch Builds" which are located in the workspace.eww file.  I have not seen an answer for the "Batch Builds" which can contain multiple projects and configurations like that of the IDE.

To create a command line that operates similarly to that, you'll have to create a batch file which calls them out explicitly as described by Ian below are references to the user's guide from IAR. I recommend doing a *-clean* beforehand if the project isn't huge to ensure all files are recompiled.

Ian's great answer is for building individual configurations of the specific project.

For reference, the [IDE Project Management and Building Guide](ftp://ftp.iar.se/WWWfiles/8051/webic/doc/EW8051_UserGuide.pdf) on Page 71 .The work space batch build is described at the bottom of page 69. This command line structure is the same for ARM as well.

> iarbuild project.ewp [-clean|-build|-make]  [-log errors|warnings|info|all]

```
iarbuild "Project_File.ewp" -clean BUILD_NAME
iarbuild "Project_File.ewp" -make BUILD_NAME -log info

// repeat for other configurations / projects
```